# How to reset the ilo5 factory generated password using API ? or ilorest Tool from remote machine?

Tags: password, ilo, reset

I have multiple HPE Gen10 servers which have ILO5 license.

Now I want to manage the server from remote system using API or HP ilorest Tool, but to authenticate, it requires a password of user administrator & it comes as tag on the server. It's a very tedious task to note down the password & reset if you have 100 to 200 servers.
Does anyone know how I can reset the password from a remote system without having old one .

Answer (score 0):

iLO_host = "https://{iLO}"
login_account = "admin"
login_password = "password"

But you use the PATCH to "Password" Action in the account (ManagerAccount) to change it.

HEre is a sample code to do it on the tool remotely 
https://github.com/HewlettPackard/python-redfish-utility/blob/master/examples/Linux/Change_Password.sh

Comment: i have said i dont have the password...but above method looks it required password can you please clarify... would request if you can share the exact syntax.